# Delete values from a 2d array in php

Tags: php

I have the following 2 dimensional array:

```
 Array ( [0] =>
             Array ( [0] => 20130202 
                     [1] => unknown 
                     [2] => 0 
                     [3] => 1 
                     [4] => 0 
                     [5] => 0 
                     [6] => 0 
                     [7] => 19022 
                     [8] => 0 
                     [9] => 0 ) 
          [1] => 
              Array ([0] => 20130202 
                     [1] => ZZ 
                     [2] => 1 
                     [3] => 0 
                     [4] => 0 
                     [5] => 0 
                     [6] => 0 
                     [7] => 4 
                     [8] => 0 
                     [9] => 0 ) 
                  *
                  *
```

I try to delete specific the following entries on the internal array: 2,4,6,7,8,9. The code that I'm using is the following one:

```
     foreach ($array_with_values as $key => $obj) {
        if ($key == 2 || $key == 4 || $key == 6 || $key == 7 || $key == 8 || $key == 9){
            unset($obj[$key]);
        }
      }
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: `foreach` only gives you the content of the array but doesn't let you modify them. So use `for` with an increment counter instead when you need to modify an array.

Answer (score 1):

use only this `unset($array_with_values[$key]);`

```
 foreach ($array_with_values as $key => $obj) {
    if ($key == 2 || $key == 4 || $key == 6 || $key == 7 || $key == 8 || $key == 9){
        unset($array_with_values[$key]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: No, this is only unsetting the `$obj` variable inside the `foreach` loop.  It won't affect `$array_with_values` at all.

Comment: @AlexDowining now check, now it will unset the $array_with_values key

Answer (score 1):

Instead of focusing of what you want to remove, you could filter what you want instead:

```
$keys = array_flip([0, 1, 3, 5]);

foreach ($outer as &$inner) {
    $inner = array_intersect_key($inner, $keys);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach ($array_with_values as $key => $obj) {
        if ($key == 2 || $key == 4 || $key == 6 || $key == 7 || $key == 8 || $key == 9){
            unset($array_with_values[$key]);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is... `unset($array_with_values[$key])`

Consider the following block of code...

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,6);

foreach($arr as $key => $a)
{
    if($a == 2)
    unset($a);
}

print_r($arr);

foreach($arr as $key => $a)
{
    if($a == 2)
    unset($arr[$key]);
}

print_r($arr);
```

I hope you got i want to explain.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
$unwanted = array(2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9);

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($outerArray); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < sizeof($unwanted); $j++) {
        unset($outerArray[$i][$unwanted[$j]]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach ($array_with_values as $key => $obj) {
    if ($key == 2 || $key == 4 || $key == 6 || $key == 7 || $key == 8 || $key == 9){
        unset($obj[$key]);
    }
  }
```

Here your keys will be 0,1 for the first array, so do like below :

```
 $delete = array (2,4,6,7,8,9);
 foreach ($array_with_values as $key => $obj) {
    foreach($delete as $val){
        unset($obj[$val]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$big_array = array(

 array(20130202 ,'unknown',0,1,0,0,0,19022,0,0),
 array(20130202 ,'ZZ',1,0,0,0,0,4,0,0)
 );

 foreach ($big_array as $ikey => $array) {


       foreach ($array as $key => $val) {

          if (in_array($key, array(2,4,6,7,8,9))) {
             unset($big_array[$ikey][$key]);
          }
       }
    }

print_r($big_array);
```